# How to perform random walk on multilayer network to predict new edges

Tags: neural-networks, predictive-models, graphical-model, random-walk, networks

I have a multi-layer network that is a union of 3 networks (field of human biology/ Omics data). The 3 networks have dense connections within each other (local), however sparse connections to each other. I want to perform random walk or node2vec on the multi-layer network in order to predict new edges and increase the multi-layer connections. I am kind of new to the field of network analysis and kind of lost in the numerous algorithms and models that do exist.

Can anyone with experience in the field suggest me an algorithm/package that can perform randomwalk/node2vec-similar walk on the graph to predict new edges?
I would rather go for something simple and kind of validated and accepted in the field (not a new fancy algorithms)

Thank you in advance :)